# Tried creating a bootable pendrive in mac, but mac doesn't recognise pendrive post erase

Tags: usb, macbook

Was using the steps mentioned here https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#3-prepare-the-usb-stick. After erasing the pendrive, mac doesn't recognise while reinserting it and I could not progress further.

Comment: If you are in MacOS try installing and using Etcher. https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Comment: Well yea that is the next step. But my mac doesn't even recognise the pendrive, that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Yeah not really an Ubuntu problem then. If Etcher does not recognise it then try this https://iboysoft.com/howto/mac-first-aid-repair-disk.html